# What is wrong with my op-amp circuit in LTspice?

Tags: operational-amplifier, ltspice

I am revisiting the topic of using LTspice for the design and analysis of electrical circuits after a hiatus of a few years.

I am creating a gain block based off an example in the textbook "SPICE-Simulation using LTspice IV", but I do not get the expected the result when I run the simulation in LTspice XVII despite everything being virtually the same between the textbook example and my LTspice version. (Please see attached images).

[image: My LTspice model]

[image: Textbook example]

I presume that my error is something very simple. Therefore, any insight that anyone with a fresh pair of eyes can provide, will be very much appreciated.

Comment: Your -2.5 V supply is actually +2.5 V in your first schematic.

Comment: Oh, yes.  That would cause what's being seen there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your voltage V3 is reversed. The effective supply of your op-amp is 0V as you have the same voltage at both positive and negative supply pins.